# Can I disable "Allow double escaping" on a SharePoint web site?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, security, iis, encode

We're working on hardening our SharePoint server, and STIG [V-76825 IISW-SI-000229](https://stigviewer.com/stig/iis_8.5_site/2018-09-18/finding/V-76825) mandates that "Double encoded URL requests must be prohibited by any IIS 8.5 website". Basically, editing the `Request Filtering` feature settings in IIS and unchecking the `Allow double escaping` checkbox.

Is this going to limit any SharePoint operations, considering the `source` parameter is escaped and used in a lot of operations? Or things like document names?

I've done a little testing, but I don't have a way to test every possible SharePoint url, and I haven't found a definitive answer searching the internet yet. If we need to leave it checked, I have to have some good documentation as to why.

Comment: Your best bet is to open a support case so you can get an official word from the product group. This will also help you if they say it isn't supported.

Comment: That's a great idea! I'll just forward them the entire guides on securing an IIS server [link](https://vaulted.io/library/disa-stigs-srgs/iis_85_server_security_technical_implementation_guide) and securing all the websites [link](https://vaulted.io/library/disa-stigs-srgs/iis_85_site_security_technical_implementation_guide), and see which ones they say to ignore. Since it's been a few years since SharePoint 2016 was released, I'm sure they've got a list by now.

Comment: Did you get a response to this from your MS support case?